# angular.js routing 404 not found error in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, angularjs, asp.net-web-api

I am writing my blog site with using angular.js and asp.net webapi. I did url  routing with angular.js. when I click url but I get 404 not found error. How to fix this problem?

```
var blogSite = angular.module("blogSite", ["ngRoute"]);
blogSite.config(['$routeProvider', function ($routeProvider) {
$routeProvider
    .when("post/:post", {
        teplateUrl: 'blogpost.html',
        controller: 'blogPostController'
    })
    .otherwise({
        redirectTo: 'index.html'
    });
}]);

blogSite.controller("mainPageController", function ($scope, $http,     $routeParams) {
var url = baseUrl + "getpost";
$http.get(url)
    .success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
        if (data.length > 0) {
            $scope.LastBlogPosts = data;
        }
        else {
            $scope.LastBlogPosts = null;
        }
    })
    .error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
        console.log(status);
    });
});

blogSite.controller("blogPostController", function ($scope, $http, $routeParams) {
 $scope.TestMessage = "Test Message"
});
```

index.html page

```
div ng-controller="mainPageController">
            <ul>
                <li ng-repeat="blogPost in LastBlogPosts">
                    <a href="post/{{blogPost.PostUrl}}" class="lastPostUrl mainPagePostTitle">{{blogPost.PostTitle}}</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div ng-view>

</div>
```

Comment: `teplateUrl: 'blogpost.html',` should be `templateUrl: 'blogpost.html',` & angular doesn''t provide an direct access to html file

Comment: i changed but error continues

Comment: mvc views folder doen't provide an access to the html files directly..from where you are trying to access the html file?

Comment: There are two projects in my solution. First BlogSite.API, Second BlogSite.UI. I didn't create blogsite.ui with mvc template. blogpost.html file is in blogsite.ui project

Comment: is there any error change in console? or you are getting the same error were getting before?

Comment: http://localhost:2569/post/avlayan-batuhan-url Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found). there is one error in console.

Comment: when i click on any link, Url seems http://localhost:2569/post/avlayan-batuhan-url. but i get 404 found error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You anchor should be having `#` to restrict redirection, putting `#` at the start of URL will keep you in same page & will keep you in SPA

```
<a href="#post/{{blogPost.PostUrl}}" class="lastPostUrl mainPagePostTitle">
  {{blogPost.PostTitle}}
</a>
```